# Cannot SSH in AWS EC2 Instance: Operation timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have been stuck on this since last night. The command I am using is `ssh -i myfile.pem ubuntu@publicIP`.

I have changed the `chmod` to 400.

When I run the command in my terminal it doesn't do anything and then after about 30 seconds I see:

> ssh: connect to host 18.234.225.93 port 22: Operation timed out

For my security groups, inbound I have selected:

- Type=SSH  Protocol=TCP    Port=22 Destination=0.0.0.0/0 and
- Type=All ICMP - IPv4  Protocol=ICMP   Port=All    Destination=0.0.0.0/0

Outbound is the same but one more row for `all traffic` at `0.0.0.0/0`

I am unsure as to what else I can do to make this work, and whether or not this is an issue on my end or AWS. I have followed some step by step instruction that I have found on here such as [How do I set up SSH access for an Amazon EC2 instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394762/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-access-for-an-amazon-ec2-instance) but with little success. If anyone can help, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Have you launched your instance in a public subnet or default VPC?

Comment: @Marcin if i understand correctly, i originally created a VPC, and then two private subnets within it. Then i attached each instance to the respected subnets.

Comment: Your instance must be in public subnet, not private, so that you can ssh to it directly.

Comment: @Marcin my route table points to my vpc. Could this be part of the issue?

Comment: I don't know how your VPC is setup. You can update your question with all its details.

Comment: @Marcin within my setting i have DNS resolutions and hostname enabled, my network ACLs are both associated the private subnets i created in my vpc, and my route table is also pointing to my vpc that i created. Is there any other info  i can provide?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description in the comments.

Your VPC has only two private subnets. When you place an instance in a private subnet, as the name "private" suggests, there is **no internet** connectivity to it, nor it can connect by default to the internet.

To be able to directly ssh into your instance, it must be place in **public subnet**. So you would have to add such a subnet to your VPC, or convert existing private subnet into public.

For public subnet you need:

- [Internet gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html) (IGW) attached to your VPC
- a route table pointing `0.0.0.0/0` to the IGW
- subnet should usually have Assign public IP enabled.

Example of a VPC with both public and private subnets is shown in:

- [VPC with public and private subnets (NAT)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html)

Comment: i have a public subnet setup, and unfortunately, the problem persists.

Comment: @dkhayutin Can you please update your question with exact details of your VPC, route tables, security groups, NACLs and more. You can take screenshots if you want.

Comment: @dkhayutin How did it go? Did you manage to connect?

Comment: Marcin sorry for the delay in responding. Yes, it turns out that the MAJOR issue was  that the subnets i had added in were not properly added to my route table. Seemed to solve the issue and i was able to then SSH!

Answer (score 0):

When an SSH connection times-out, it is normally an indication that network traffic is not getting to the Amazon EC2 instance.

Things to check:

- The instance is running **Linux**
- The instance is launched in a **public subnet**, which is defined as having a Route Table entry to points to an Internet Gateway
- The instance has a **public IP address**, which you are using for the connection
- The **Network Access Control Lists** (NACLs) are set to their default "Allow All" values
- A **Security Group** associated with the instance that permits inbound access on port 22 (SSH) either from your IP address, or from the Internet (`0.0.0.0/0`)
- Your **corporate network** permits an outbound SSH connection (try alternate networks, eg home vs work vs tethered to your phone)

See also: [Troubleshooting connecting to your instance - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html)