# Amazon Web Services - EC2 instance operation timed out on mac ssh

Tags: macos, ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terminal

I am trying to connect to my EC2 instance through SSH on Terminal.  I am able to access the instance on CoRD, but I cannot access it on SSH or RDP through Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection.  I am just trying to learn the system, so I am using the default security group which is opening all ICMP, TCP, UDP ports.

Comment: What kind of system do you have. SSH only works on linux, while RDP only works on windows.

Comment: the instance is a Windows Micro, I am trying to connect to it with a Mac.  Microsoft created an RDP application for Mac.

Comment: You wont be using ssh, only RDP. Port 3309 needs to be open in the security group to your location.

Comment: I am using the default security group that has all ports open

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the same problem I was having. I was able to solve it by using suggestions given on [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813843/possible-reasons-for-timeout-when-trying-to-access-ec2-instance). I think the confusion is with the default security group. What it shows in front of it as "All ports" does not mean that all ports are open, but rather that the security group includes all ports. 
I am including the steps I took, hoping it would help, if you haven't figured it out by now.

1. On the sidebar, under `Network and Security`, choose `Security Groups`.
2. On the list of the security groups shown, choose the one you want to configure to allow an inbound connection (`default VPC security group` in this example).
3. On the bottom of the page, choose `Inbound` tab and press Edit.
4. For type, choose SSH or RDP. The protocol will be automatically set to TCP, the port range to 22 and for the source if you choose `My IP`, it will set it to your computer's IP.
5. After finishing these steps, simply start your instance and connect to it using SSH or RDP.

These steps worked for me but I am a beginner and learning, so there may have been some other small details that I may have missed. If others notice it, I'm sure they will point it out.