# Connection timed out error AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I keep getting the following error while trying to connect o my AWS instance ,I followed the links below and added my local machine's IP to the list of inbound rules in the active security group but still see the problem,can anyone provide assistance on how to debug and overcome this problem?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectionTimeout

[Possible reasons for timeout when trying to access EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813843/possible-reasons-for-timeout-when-trying-to-access-ec2-instance)

```
Error connecting to ec2-52-39-2-81.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com, reason:
-> Connection timed out: no further information
```

Comment: I'm not sure how anyone could help you given the amount of information you've provided. What type of sever, Windows or linux? How are you trying to connect, ssh? Did you actually open the correct port in the security group? Are you positive you have the correct hostname for the server?

Comment: Hi Mark - can you please tell me what all information is needed here and how to get them?its a linux server,trying to connect via  A Java SSH Client directly from my browse,22 is the port for inbound traffice