# aws ec2 can not secureshell from one subnet/vpc to another subnet/vpc

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, subnet

I have an aws ec2 machine (`172.18.18.133`) on subnetwork with CidrBlock `172.18.18.0/23`.
Have secureshell ingress ip open for `10.0.0.0/8` and `172.23.0.0/18` (*ignore `"0.0.0.0/0"` in firewall as I'm playing with it because specific source CidrBlock did not work*)

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids sg-659fd31p --profile aws-federated --region us-west-2
{
    "SecurityGroups": [
        {
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1", 
                    "PrefixListIds": [], 
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [], 
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                }
            ], 
            "Description": "VPC Security Group", 
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "restapi-dev", 
                    "Key": "elasticbeanstalk:environment-name"
                }, 
                {
                    "Value": "awseb-e-8gx8kmq9dj-stack", 
                    "Key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-name"
                }, 
                {
                    "Value": "AWSEBSecurityGroup", 
                    "Key": "aws:cloudformation:logical-id"
                }, 
                {
                    "Value": "restapi-dev", 
                    "Key": "Name"
                }, 
                {
                    "Value": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:033814027302:stack/awseb-e-8gx8kmq9dj-stack/605642e0-3eb8-11e7-a388-503ac9ec2499", 
                    "Key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-id"
                }, 
                {
                    "Value": "e-8gx8kmq9dj", 
                    "Key": "elasticbeanstalk:environment-id"
                }
            ], 
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [], 
                    "FromPort": 80, 
                    "IpRanges": [], 
                    "ToPort": 80, 
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp", 
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [
                        {
                            "UserId": "033814027302", 
                            "GroupId": "sg-ee81cd95"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                }, 
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [], 
                    "FromPort": 22, 
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "10.0.0.0/8"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "172.23.0.0/18"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "ToPort": 22, 
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp", 
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [], 
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                }
            ], 
            "GroupName": "awseb-e-8gx8kmq9dj-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-4J0FPNXL840U", 
            "VpcId": "vpc-5374e434", 
            "OwnerId": "033814027302", 
            "GroupId": "sg-659fd31p"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to secureshell connect to above machine from another machine which is on **different VPC** and CidrBlock `172.23.0.0/18`.

But I can not connect from ec2 machine with Ip address `172.23.38.167`
to above target machine.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-23-38-167 ~]$ ssh -v -i /home/ec2-user/.ssh/staging-api.pem ec2-user@172.18.18.133

OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 172.18.18.133 [172.18.18.133] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 172.18.18.133 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 172.18.18.133 port 22: Connection timed out
```

I do have `.pem` file `~/.ssh`

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-23-38-167 ~]$ ll ~/.ssh/
total 20
-rw-------. 1 ec2-user ec2-user 1675 May 24 02:45 staging-api.pem
-rw-------. 1 ec2-user ec2-user  398 Apr  8 21:29 authorized_keys
-rw-------. 1 root     root     1766 Apr 23 20:06 gitkey_rsa
-rw-r--r--. 1 root     root      386 Apr 23 20:06 gitkey_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user  413 May 20 21:02 known_hosts
```

**Note**: I have few ec2 VMs in the same subnet and I can do secureshell between them.

### **Target/Source VPC config**

Not sure but the problem could be with the [routing table on the VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-ssh-troubleshooting/).

The routing table config of the VPC with target machine which I want secureshell into is below. Don't know the purpose of all these 6/7 routes but understand [NAT gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-gateway.html#nat-gateway-troubleshooting) to enable VMs in a private subnet to connect to the Internet or other AWS services.

```
$ aws ec2 describe-route-tables --route-table-ids rtb-9e0337f9  --profile aws-federated --region us-west-2
{
    "RouteTables": [
        {
            "Associations": [
                {
                    "SubnetId": "subnet-a1ec23e8", 
                    "RouteTableAssociationId": "rtbassoc-d8ffbbbe", 
                    "Main": false, 
                    "RouteTableId": "rtb-9e0337f9"
                }
            ], 
            "RouteTableId": "rtb-9e0337f9", 
            "VpcId": "vpc-5374e434", 
            "PropagatingVgws": [], 
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "fff000", 
                    "Key": "Permissions"
                }, 
                {
                    "Value": "us-west-2b", 
                    "Key": "PhysicalLocation"
                }, 
                {
                    "Value": "InternalSubnet01AZ1RouteTable", 
                    "Key": "aws:cloudformation:logical-id"
                }, 
                {
                    "Value": "fff000-vpc-nonprod-prayagupd-vpc-01-VPCTeamNestedStackTemplate-1EH2K9THBASPW", 
                    "Key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-name"
                }, 
                {
                    "Value": "rtb_nonprod-prayagupd-vpc-01_internal_az1", 
                    "Key": "Name"
                }, 
                {
                    "Value": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:033814027302:stack/fff000-vpc-nonprod-prayagupd-vpc-01-VPCTeamNestedStackTemplate-1EH2K9THBASPW/f7e06c10-ee60-11e6-92e6-503a90a9c435", 
                    "Key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-id"
                }, 
                {
                    "Value": "internal", 
                    "Key": "Designation"
                }
            ], 
            "Routes": [
                {
                    "Origin": "CreateRoute", 
                    "DestinationCidrBlock": "172.16.2.0/23", 
                    "State": "active", 
                    "VpcPeeringConnectionId": "pcx-c67fffaf"
                }, 
                {
                    "Origin": "CreateRoute", 
                    "DestinationCidrBlock": "172.16.4.0/23", 
                    "State": "active", 
                    "VpcPeeringConnectionId": "pcx-c67fffaf"
                }, 
                {
                    "Origin": "CreateRoute", 
                    "DestinationCidrBlock": "172.16.122.0/23", 
                    "State": "active", 
                    "VpcPeeringConnectionId": "pcx-f0f76299"
                }, 
                {
                    "Origin": "CreateRoute", 
                    "DestinationCidrBlock": "172.16.104.0/21", 
                    "State": "active", 
                    "VpcPeeringConnectionId": "pcx-7483081d"
                }, 
                {
                    "GatewayId": "local", 
                    "DestinationCidrBlock": "172.18.16.0/21", 
                    "State": "active", 
                    "Origin": "CreateRouteTable"
                }, 
                {
                    "GatewayId": "vgw-cb23fbd5", 
                    "DestinationCidrBlock": "192.168.0.0/16", 
                    "State": "active", 
                    "Origin": "CreateRoute"
                }, 
                {
                    "GatewayId": "vgw-cb23fbd5", 
                    "DestinationCidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/8", 
                    "State": "active", 
                    "Origin": "CreateRoute"
                }, 
                {
                    "Origin": "CreateRoute", 
                    "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0", 
                    "NatGatewayId": "nat-0dbd1eca0fe1fcb8e", 
                    "State": "active"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**For Source VPC, Similar route config as target VPC,**

```
    {
        "Origin": "CreateRoute", 
        "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0", 
        "NatGatewayId": "nat-0b6d136887df6f792", 
        "State": "active"
    }
```

NAT config for source VPC is

```
$ aws ec2 describe-nat-gateways --nat-gateway-id nat-0b6d136887df6f792 --profile aws-federated --region us-west-2
{
    "NatGateways": [
        {
            "NatGatewayAddresses": [
                {
                    "PublicIp": "34.208.30.85", 
                    "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-43d8c630", 
                    "AllocationId": "eipalloc-d47488b2", 
                    "PrivateIp": "172.23.248.220"
                }
            ], 
            "VpcId": "vpc-a77a82c2", 
            "State": "available", 
            "NatGatewayId": "nat-0b6d136887df6f792", 
            "SubnetId": "subnet-b267b2d7", 
            "CreateTime": "2017-03-30T18:16:05.767Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

### Resource

[Possible reasons for timeout when trying to access EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29151526/432903)

Comment: change `172.23.0.0/18` to `172.23.0.0/16`

Comment: how would that make a difference? My source machine is on `172.23.0.0/18` Cidr

Comment: /18 range is between `172.23.192.1` to `172.23.255.254`     and `172.23.38.167` is not in that range

Comment: I might be wrong with range calculation , but worth a try

Comment: `172.23.0.0/18` should start with `172.23.0.0` to `172.23.63.254`. `172.23.38.167` would obvisously be in that range, as `38` lies in `[0, 64]` http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=172.23.0.0&mask1=18&mask2=

Comment: hmm, since they are in different VPC, there is a chance request is sent through public IP of that VPC. might worth a try to check that as well mate

Comment: public ip of VPC? don't know what does that mean. I checked my target VPC routing table which might be blocking the `172.23.0.0/18` but not sure what is `GatewayId` there

Comment: try `curl icanhazip.com` to get your client machine outgoing ip on your client server (other vpc than your source). and just for testing add that to your iptable and see if it works,

Comment: @nafas [`curl ipecho.net/plain`](https://askubuntu.com/a/145017/37643) or `curl http://checkip.amazonaws.com` on client ec2-machine (that I want to secureshell from) gives me `34.208.30.85`. Adding the CidrBlock `34.208.30.85/32` to the target machine aws firewall does not work either. I need to dig into the `iptables` though. Don't know how to check that using `iptables` linux tool